# Peek in iOS 9 App Crashing

Tags: ios, uitableview, peek, 3dtouch

I am trying to do Peek and Pop in my iOS 9 capable app.  The view in question has a UITableView, so I have in my code:

```
- (UIViewController *)previewingContext:(id<UIViewControllerPreviewing>)previewingContext viewControllerForLocation:(CGPoint)location {

    // check if we're not already displaying a preview controller
    if ([self.presentedViewController isKindOfClass:[WebViewController class]]) {
        return nil;
    }

    // shallow press: return the preview controller here (peek)
        self.webViewController = [[[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];




    return self.webViewController;
}
- (void)previewingContext:(id<UIViewControllerPreviewing>)previewingContext commitViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToCommit {

    // deep press: bring up the commit view controller (pop)
    self.webViewController = [[[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];


    [self showViewController:self.webViewController sender:self];
}
```

`WebViewController` is the `ViewController` I have already set up to display the content when the row of the tableview is selected.  The error I get is:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSCFConstantString stringByAppendingString:]: nil argument'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x182160f5c 0x19764bf80 0x182160ea4 0x182fb8868 0x1001307a4 0x1876cf9ac 0x1876cf720 0x187a025f8 0x187960844 0x18796cde4 0x1876a91e4 0x182117c30 0x1821159d4 0x182115e04 0x182044dc0 0x18d4e0088 0x18771ef60 0x10014ca68 0x197e6a8b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Sounds like a good time to google "Xcode exception breakpoint"

Comment: @GradyPlayer With that on, the app crashes before anything even happens.  With exception breakpoint off, it runs fine until the peek.

Comment: Sounds like you activated "all exception breakpoints". If you use NSURLSession for example, this throws immediately because they use exceptions for control flow. Choose "use only Objc breakpoints".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your log it's saying exactly what is wrong with your code:

> -[__NSCFConstantString stringByAppendingString:]: nil argument'

You are performing `stringByAppendingString` passing a value that is **`nil`**

Also, `autorelease` is not used anymore if you are using ARC (it's default by now)